# Select element dose not display selected value in it's input field - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am making a crud application in Laravel. I make edit option, when I click on edit option it displays data from database according to corresponding id. It displays all values in input fields that I have entered while inserting data, but select element dose not display any data in its input field.

Page displaying all data from database

[image]

When I click on edit, it displays edit form as shown in the below picture

[image: Edit From Displaying data]

You can see all input fields displaying correct data from database but select element dose not displaying any value.

Code for this form is

```
@foreach($result as $list)
    <div class="container">
        <!------------ Row 1 ------------>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>NAME</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_name }}">
                </div>
                @error('name')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>PHONE</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_phone }}">
                </div>
                @error('phone')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_city }}">
                </div>
                @error('city')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>INSTALLER NAME</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="instaname" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->inst_name }}" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!------------ Row 2 ------------>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>STORE NAME</label>
                    <select type="text" name="storename" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->storename }}"> 
                        <option> ~ SELECT STORE NAME ~</option>
                        <option>PACKAGES</option>
                        <option>EMPORIUM</option>
                        <option>FORTRESS</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                @error('storename')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ORDER DATE</label>
                    <input type="date"  name="odate" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->odate }}">
                </div>
                @error('odate')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>INSTALLATION DATE</label>
                    <input type="date"  name="instadate" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->inst_date }}">
                </div>
                @error('instadate')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>BRAND NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="bname" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->brandname }}">
                </div>
                @error('bname')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>                 
        </div>

        <!------------ Row 3 ------------>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>PRODUCT NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" id="add" name="pname" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_order }}"> 
                </div>
                @error('pname')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ORDER STATUS</label>
                    <select name="ostatus" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_order_status }}">
                        <option> ~ SELECT STATUS ~ </option>
                        <option>PROCESSED</option>
                        <option>COMPLETED</option>
                        <option>FAILED</option>
                        <option>CANCELLED</option>
                        <option>PENDING</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                @error('ostatus')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>INSTALLATION DONE BY</label>
                    <select  name="doneby" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->inst_done_by }}">
                        <option> ~ DONE BY ~ </option>
                        <option>PCES</option>
                        <option>SELF</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                @error('doneby')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDITIONAL COMMENTS</label>
                    <input type="text" name="comments" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->comments }}">
                </div>
                @error('comments')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>

        <!------------ Row 4 ------------>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="{{ $list->cust_address }}" >
                </div>
                @error('address')
                    <span id="field_error">{{$message}}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>                     
    </div>
@endforeach
```

How can this problem be sorted out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just putting the value in select won't make the option selected. You have to add the `selected` attribute in an option to make it selected.

```
<select type="text" name="storename" class="form-control"> 
    <option> ~ SELECT STORE NAME ~</option>
    <option {{ $list->storename == 'PACKAGES' ? 'selected' : '' }}>PACKAGES</option>
    <option {{ $list->storename == 'EMPORIUM' ? 'selected' : '' }}>EMPORIUM</option>
    <option {{ $list->storename == 'FORTRESS' ? 'selected' : '' }}>FORTRESS</option>
</select>
```

Same applies for the ORDER STATUS selection. However I can see you are not using any value for options. It's good to use a value for each option. Consider using a unique value for each option.

Answer (score 1):

Value is not getting displayed in select because you have used value in `select tag` instead of `option tag` and add keyword `selected` in option tag

```
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->

<select name="choice">
<option value="first">First Value</option>
<option value="second" selected>Second Value</option>
<option value="third">Third Value</option>
</select>
```